# Select Acumulativo Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

La consulta es para SqlServer 2008 r2

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta acumulativa pero los ejemplos que voy viendoy probando no me funcionan, a ver si aquí encuentro la solución, si es que la hay.

tengo la siguiente tabla
Campos: Codigo, tipo, cantidad

[image: tabla original]

me gustaría poder hacer una consulta que vaua acumulando en una columna la suma de la columna cantidad por cada codigo, pero haciendo un reset a la suma si el tipo es 2

El resultado que quiero obtener sería el siguiente

[image: resultado final]

Cuando el tipo es 2, la cuenta empieza de nuevo.

Se puede hacer con un select?

Gracias

Comment: No eres muy claro amigo, el total con base a que campos se calcula y poner imagenes no ayuda mucho en vez de eso podrias poner el script de tus tablas para tratar de ayudarte saludos

Comment: Gracias Edgar, voy a intentar explicarlo mejor.

Comment: Se puede hacer con un select, necesitas usar un función ventana (Window function).

Comment: Gracias Jose, voy a buscar por google algún ejemplo.

Comment: Por ejemplo por que el segundo da 8 , se como se podria resolver con un  OVER(PARTITION BY Campo) AS Total , pero quiero saber por que da 8 el segundo

Comment: Hola Edgar, el Total 8 de la segunda fila, sale de sumar la cantidad 5 de la primera fila + la cantidad 3 de la segunda fila...

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he encontrado una sentencia buena para mi.

```
with AcumulaCant as (
select
 d.idrecno,
 d.tipmov,
 d.codart,
 d.codalm,
 d.cant
from movsto d
)
select *,
CantAcum = (
select SUM(cant)
from AcumulaCant c
where c.idrecno <= AcumulaCant.idrecno
and c.codart = AcumulaCant.codart
and c.codalm = AcumulaCant.codalm),
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by codart,codalm order by idrecno desc) as rn 
from AcumulaCant
order by AcumulaCant.codart,AcumulaCant.codalm,AcumulaCant.idrecno desc
```

con esta sentencia consigo el acumulado de la suma de cantidades por referencia

Gracias por los comentarios recibidos